# scrollabe jqm popup doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I am developing a jQuery Mobile project which i have an extendable popup in it but when i extent the text in the popup, it doesn't scroll.
I have checked `overflow: scroll` and all the other options in overflow, but none worked. but when i extent the text i see a bar appears on the right side of the popup, but no scroll.

this is the last code i tried and did not work as well

```
$("#buttonTest").click(function() {
    $('#Popup').css('overflow', 'scroll');        
    $('#Popup').popup('open');
});
```

and this is the popup itself

```
<div data-role="popup" id="Popup" data-transition="flow">
    <div class="newsCards">
        <img src="images/back.svg">
        <h4> header</h4>
        <div class="newsFader">
            <!-- extended text which is hidden at first -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also post the code you use to define the popup?

Comment: The element that needs to scroll is the div with "newsCards".   $('.newsCards').css('overflow', 'scroll'); as this is the element that is overflowing. It's hard to say for sure without seeing all the css for #Popup.  And it's best to put those declarations in the css rather than setting css properties via jQuery since the scrolling property isn't likely to change.

Comment: unfortunately that did not work ... the popup itself has some padding position color border z-index and that's all ...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your use case by creating the popup and styling it, the ideal way to make the test scrollable is by using css only.
This is my scrollable newsFader class i took for the text container.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .newsFader {
        width: 80%;
        height: 50px;
        overflow: scroll;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Maybe the text was not scrolling beacuse the size of the container was not defined forcing it to adapt to its content. Anyway this is the popup code i tried and scrolled correctly:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="Popup" data-transition="flow">
    <div class="newsCards">
        <img src="">
        <h4> header</h4>
        <div class="newsFader">
            <!-- extended text which is hidden at first -->
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
            Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
            fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
            qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps you, Happy Coding!

Comment: that did not work is think i need to rewrite this part again part by part and see what will happen ... thanks anyway

Comment: Ok, sorry to hear that if you need more help let me know